# Log::info in another file with laravel using channel

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I have a Job that runs each 10 minutes, and is flooding the `laravel.log`, so I want to log all his activity to `/storage/logs/customJob.log`

In `/config/logging.ph`p, I added a channel:

```
'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],
        // ...
        'customJob' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/customJob.log'),
            'level' => 'info',
        ]
    ],
```

and call it in my job with

```
Log::channel('customJob')->info("test...");
```

Weird thing is when I try it with tinker or locally, it works well.

But in production, I can see:

in `logs/customJob.log`, I can see the logs for 10:30, 11:40, 12:10, seems random.

in `logs/laravel.log`, I can see:

```
[2021-05-19 12:40:25] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured
    logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object]
    (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key \"driver\" at
    /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:195)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(195):
    Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
    #1 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(118):
    Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve()
    #2 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(98):
    Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get()
    #3 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(87):
    Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
    #4 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261):
    Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->channel()
    #5 /home/ubuntu/project/app/Jobs/BlockchainToDb.php(104): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()
    #6 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36):
    App\\Jobs\\BlockchainToDb->handle()
    #7 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40):
    Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
    #8 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93):
    Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
    #9 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37):
    Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
    #10 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(611):
    Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
    #11 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(128):
    Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
    #12 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128):
    Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}()
    #13 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103):
    Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
    #14 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(132):
    Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
    #15 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(118):
    Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow()
    #16 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}()
    #17 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103):
    Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
    #18 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(120):
    Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
    #19 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(70):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware()
    #20 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(98):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->call()
    #21 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(410):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->fire()
    #22 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(360):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process()
    #23 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(158):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob()
    #24 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(117):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon()
    #25 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker()
    #26 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36):
    Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
    #27 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40):
    Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
    #28 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93):
    Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
    #29 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37):
    Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
    #30 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(611):
    Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
    #31 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136):
    Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
    #32 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256):
    Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
    #33 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121):
    Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
    #34 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(971):
    Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
    #35 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(290):
    Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
    #36 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(166):
    Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
    #37 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(92):
    Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
    #38 /home/ubuntu/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129):
    Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
    #39 /home/ubuntu/project/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
    #40 {main} "}
```

I can see those warning for all the missing timestamps in customJob.log ie 10:40, 10:50, 11:00, 11:10, 11:20, 11:30, 11:50, etc.

Where BlockchainToDb.php(104) correspond to:

```
Log::channel('customJob')->info("Skipping...");
```

I also took care of cleaning cache, config, views and route in production:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Why is it behaving this way ???

Comment: I ended up rebooting my server, and it worked. Not sure how to do it without rebooting...